# Getting Vuex error in watcher but I'm not using Vuex [Nuxt]

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, vuex

I am trying to change an object property in an array [{ text: 'some text' value: 'some value, active: false }, etc..] from false to true when I select the checkbox that is bound to a v-model:

```
<v-col v-for="(item, i) in searchModule.allHeaders" :key='i' cols='2'>
<v-checkbox
  v-model='selectedColumnHeaders'
  :label="item.text"
  :value="item"
  color="primary"
  hide-details
></v-checkbox>
</v-col>
```

I am trying to do this inside Vue watcher, so when the array changes when I check or uncheck, I update it the array object properties, but when I try to do this, I am getting this weird Vuex error! And I'm not even using Vuex here! Is this a framework bug or am I misunderstanding how watchers work? I am using Nuxt by the way.

Here is my code in the watcher:

```
watch: {
        // columns for table regen
        selectedColumnHeaders(newVal, oldVal) {
            /*
            This is how we change the header's active status, by default some are active and some aren't, 
            but when a user checks the check box to regenerate a table, we need to change these active key-value pairs, we do it here.
            */
            if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                this.selectedColumnHeaders.map((header) => {
                    (header.active === false) ? header.active = true : null;
                });
            }
        }
    },
```

It works when I click on headers that were already checked when the Vue instance was created ([{ text: 'some text' value: 'some value, active: true }, etc..]), but when I click on a checkbox where the active property was false when the Vue instance was created, I get this error:

"Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."

There's no Vuex in this component or the parent component! (It is present elswhere in the app), but the data I am "mutating" is not in the store.... Very confused, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else encounters this, I resolved it by adding "export const strict = false" to my /store/index.vue, no idea why this was triggering Vuex but it is and this resolved the error.

Comment: The strict mode is actually here to prevent mutability of your variables. So yeah..you can disable it but it should not be disabled actually since it helps you write better code. If you want to not have this error anymore, do not mutate your objects (clone them and edit the copy for example).

Comment: @kissu Yeah it's used so people aren't mutating Vuex state directly which I think is definitely better code, the thing is is I'm not using Vuex here, I'm trying to mutate the local state which is not connected to Vuex, hence my confusion and frustration

Comment: It's probably because of the way that Vue detects that kind of mutation, there is probably no difference on how it triggers the warning. Even if it's related to Vuex, it also applies in some instances.